# AutoMapper: Order of invocation of Resolve() when multiple IValueResolvers are used

Tags: c#, automapper, resolver

I'm using AutoMapper, and I declared a mapping rule as follows:

```
   CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ActivityName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom<NameResolver>())
      .ForMember(dest => dest.HistName, opt => opt.MapFrom<HistNameResolver>())
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Asset, opt => opt.MapFrom<AssetResolver>())
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Props, opt => opt.MapFrom<PropsResolver>())
```

I'm writing unit tests for this rule, but I have trouble understanding the **order** by which resolvers are invoked (order of calling their `Resolve()` method).

I wrote a unit test for `NameResolver` and thought it would be the first resolver whose `Resolve()` method would be called. While debugging I discovered I was wrong. The first resolver invoked was `AssetResolver`.

"Oh fine! I guess resolvers are taken care of alphabetically." I thought. I was wrong again. Debugging showed that the order resolvers were invoked through their `Resolve()` method was:

`AssetResolver` -> `NameResolver` -> `HistNameResolver` -> `PropsResolver`

`AssetResolver` moved to the front of the queue, while the remaining resolvers were "processed" in the order they were declared on the mapping rule. I don't understand why they are invoked in this order. Can anyone shed some light on this? Can I change this order in any way? Thank you!

Comment: You have too many resolvers here. It seems easier to write a custom type converter and then the order is obvious.

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu Thank you for the suggestion. I'll propose this

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this by calling `SetMappingOrder(int)`.

For example:

```
CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => 
    {
        opt.MapFrom<NameResolver>();
        opt.SetMappingOrder(5);
    }
```

Although I would also consider Lucian Bargaoanu's comment about using a type converter.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me, and providing me with a way to set the mapping order. But do you know what's the "default" way of assigning mapping order when it is not explicitly defined?

Comment: That's undefined. By default, there is no order.